# Create EventReceiver for Permission List

Tags: 2010, list, events

I want to create event receiver for Permission list that located at /_layouts/User.aspx page. I think if i knew `ListTemplateId` of this list I would be able to handle its event. Does anyone know its `ListTemplateId` and its title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, that information is not stored in a plain list and you cannot add even receivers when a user or group is added or permissions are assigned. Applicable to MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010.

Having said that, Microsoft realized a genuine need of such scenarios and made the events available in SharePoint 2013. Check this link: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/28/sharepoint-2013-new-event-receiver-for-groupsusersrolesinheritance/

Comment: Yep, this is what I need ))) but I use SharePoint 2010

Comment: You are out of luck, sorry! If you want custom code when a group or user is created, you can write your own Application Page, provide interface and call Sharepoint API to add group or user and execute other code which you would otherwise write if the events were available. But with SP10, it's not possible.