# how to detect when a user granted the access on a site?

Tags: access, notifications, farm-admin

I have a scenario in which the farm administrators as well as the site collection administrator are not the administrator of a sub site.

Is there a solution to detect when these farm or site collection administrators grant access for a certain user on this site and then notify the real site administrator?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this you have to write custom code. SharePoint 2013 introduced a new event receiver class called "SPSecurityEventReceiver".

The custom event receiver class must derive from SPSecurityEventReceiver

Reference [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/create-groupuseradded-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Another way would be to develop a timer job which reads the audit log for the site to determine which groups have been updated, then fire a workflow or code from that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But we are using SharePoint 2010. Is there an equivalent solution for SharePoint 2010?

Comment: there no event receiver to do this activity . you have to go with 2nd option (audit log)

Comment: well, i've also just found this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44655/create-eventreceiver-for-permission-list